# Cannot make Tomcat 9.0.75 work with ORDS 22.2 or ORDS 23.1

Tags: oracle-apex, tomcat9, oracle-ords

I am installing Oracle Apex 23.1 and to access the Developer Interface and the Applications, I am installing Tomcat 9.0.75 (Windows) and ORDS 23.1.

When i run the ORDS as a standalone server, everything works fine.

As I try to run ORDS with Tomcat, it returns an error informing that the /ords resource is not avaliable. Searching in the Tomcat logs, I found in catalina log file the following entries:

`05-Jun-2023 14:30:47.570 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file 05-Jun-2023 14:30:47.616 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/ords] startup failed due to previous errors 0`

Searching futher, in the localhost log file I have found the error at the end of the post, informing that "Error configuring application listener of class [oracle.dbtools.entrypoint.WebApplicationEntryPoint]
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/dbtools/entrypoint/WebApplicationEntryPoint has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class [oracle.dbtools.entrypoint.WebApplicationEntryPoint])"

I have already downloaded and installed the lastest versions of Java JDK and Java JRE, changed the System Path variable, changed also the Java Virtual Machine Address in Tomcat. All necessary users are unlocked on Oracle Database. I have even downgraded the ORDS to version 22.2.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Below are the contents of the localhost log file from Tomcat:

`05-Jun-2023 14:30:47.570 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class [oracle.dbtools.entrypoint.WebApplicationEntryPoint] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/dbtools/entrypoint/WebApplicationEntryPoint has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class [oracle.dbtools.entrypoint.WebApplicationEntryPoint]) at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2475) at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:875) at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1376) at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220) at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:487) at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:469) at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:141) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4421) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4946) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:662) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1910) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:898) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:914) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478) 05-Jun-2023 14:30:47.570 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)`

Comment: "I have already downloaded and installed the lastest versions of Java JDK and Java JRE" - no, you should be running one of the 2 supported versions of java, either 11 or 17

Answer (score 0):

you set your config url in tomcat.

Stop your server go to tomcat webapps directory
Edit the file web.xml (webapps/ords/WEB-INF/web.xml)
Set the config url

config.url
**you_ords_config_url**

in my case that's: C:\ords-23.1.4.150.1808\config

and restart tomcat.